# Need to take previous row's calculation and add to it based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a collection of routes with a sequence of stops they were run in and the amount of time it took to get to each one. I only know the time we got to the first stop. What I need to do is figure out what time we left from each stop and when we arrived to each stop.

So what I'm trying to do is figure out a way to say:

```
df['Pickup Time'] = np.where(df['Sequence'] == 1, df['First Stop'] - df['Drive Time'], df['Pickup Time'].shift(1) + df['Drive Time'])
```

This would say for 'Sequence' 1, take the 'Drive Time' and subtract it from the 'First Stop' time, otherwise take the 'Pickup Time' from the previous row and add the 'Drive Time' to it. But I can't actually do this because the df['Pickup Time'] isn't yet defined, so I can't reference it in my np.where statement.

I have also tried it this way, but am getting a similar error:

```
for i in range(1, len(df8)): 
      df['Pickup Time'] = np.where(df.loc[i, 'Sequence'] == 1, pd.to_datetime(df.loc[i, 'First Stop']) - df.loc[i, 'Drive Time'], df[i - 1, 'Depart Time'] + df[i, 'Drive Time']))
```

Is there any way to calculate the Pickup Time based on the previous row's Pickup Time, if I don't know what the previous row's Pickup Time is until doing the calculation?

(I'm sorry, I don't know how to include the DataFrame in a pretty format here, so I had to use an HTML table.)

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">  <thead>    <tr style="text-align: right;">      <th></th>      <th>Route</th>      <th>Sequence</th>      <th>First Stop</th>      <th>Drive Time</th>    </tr>  </thead>  <tbody>    <tr>      <th>0</th>      <td>123</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>2019-11-02T17:22:41</td>      <td>00:26:38</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>1</th>      <td>123</td>     <td>2</td>      <td>2019-11-02T17:22:41</td>      <td>00:07:30</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>2</th>      <td>123</td>      <td>3</td>      <td>2019-11-02T17:22:41</td>      <td>00:02:44</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>3</th>      <td>123</td>      <td>4</td>      <td>2019-11-02T17:22:41</td>      <td>00:16:25</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>4</th>      <td>123</td>      <td>5</td>      <td>2019-11-02T17:22:41</td>      <td>00:18:04</td>    </tr> 


<tr style="text-align: right;"> <tr>      <th>5</th>      <td>125</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>2019-11-02T19:22:41</td>      <td>00:16:38</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>6</th>      <td>125</td>     <td>2</td>      <td>2019-11-02T19:22:41</td>      <td>00:08:30</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>7</th>      <td>125</td>      <td>3</td>      <td>2019-11-02T19:22:41</td>      <td>00:04:44</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>8</th>      <td>125</td>      <td>4</td>      <td>2019-11-02T19:22:41</td>      <td>00:16:25</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>9</th>      <td>125</td>      <td>5</td>      <td>2019-11-02T19:22:41</td>      <td>00:12:04</td>    </tr>  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly: for rows where `Sequence == 1`, we do `First Stop + Drive Time` (or `First Stop - Drive Time`? The code and the text are ambiguous). For all other rows I use this calculated `Pickup time`. In other words: We have one unique `Pickup Time` for each route and all rows within the same route have the same `Pickup Time`. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, I had a couple confusing parts in my previous question. I fixed them in the update. But let me address them here:
1. Yes, for Sequence 1, it should be 'First Stop' - 'Drive Time'', which equals 'Pickup Time'
2. For non Sequence 1, it should be the result of the previous row's 'Pickup Time' + that current row's 'Drive Time'
Does that make more sense? 
The 'First Stop' time will be the same for each row in the 'Route' because I only know what time they arrived to one stop.

Comment: Just saw your answer now, after having posted my answer. Ok, so I'll need to edit my answer, so hang on. One more question: The `route` variable does not need to be considered? So for example for row index==8 in your example I take the Pickup time from the previous row (index ==7) and not from the previous row of the same route (index==4)?

Comment: Sorry, the Route doesn't really need to be considered because each Sequence of 1 will start a new Route. There was a typo in my test data that had the wrong route in index of 8. I fixed that. Good catch though.

Comment: I adjusted my answer now. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Closer, and I appreciate all of your help but unfortunately not quite. So what you show in index 2 is the 'Pickup Time' of Sequence 1 (index 0) plus the the 'Drive Time' of index 2.
What I actually want for index 2 is the 'Pickup Time' of index 1 plus the 'Drive Time' of index 1. And for index 3 is the 'Pickup Time' of index 2 plus the 'Drive Time of index 2. 

In Excel it would be easy. It'd be something like this: If(current_row['Sequence']=1, current_row['First Stop'] - current_row['Drive Time'], previous_row['Pickup Time'] + previous_row['Drive Time'])

Comment: Ah, now I understand (I think :) ). Adjusted the solution again, is this it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion follows a three step approach:

1. Calculate the pickup times for all rows where `Sequence == 1`
2. Forward fill the calculated values using the pandas `fillna` method.
3. Add the drive time for all rows where `Sequence > 1` using `apply`

**Data preparation**

First, we need to ensure the correct data types for columns:

```
df['First Stop'] = pd.to_datetime(df['First Stop'])
df['Drive Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Drive Time'])
```

Now we prepopulate the target column, into which we will later insert the values:

```
df['Pickup Time'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.NaT)
```

**1. Calculate values**

Now we can do the first step, calculating the values just for the `Sequence == 1` rows:

```
df.loc[df.Sequence.eq(1), 'Pickup Time'] = df.loc[df.Sequence.eq(1), 'First Stop'] - df.loc[df.Sequence.eq(1), 'Drive Time']
```

**2. Fill up missing values**

The second step makes use of `fillna`. By specifying the `method=ffill`, we forward fill.

```
df['Pickup Time'] = df['Pickup Time'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

**3. Add the drive time in the appropriate rows**

We create a helper data series called `temp`, in which we store the cumulative sum of the drive time for each route. For this we temporarily need to convert the data type of the `Drive Time` column to numeric, becuase `cumsum()` does not work on `timedelta`.

```
df['Drive Time'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Drive Time'])
temp = df.groupby('Route')['Drive Time'].cumsum().apply(pd.to_timedelta)
df['Drive Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Drive Time']) # Convert back to timedelta
```

Now we can calculate the pickup time by adding the shifted `temp` and `Pickup Time` series for rows with `Sequence == 1`

```
df['Pickup Time'] = np.where(df.Sequence > 1, df['Pickup Time'].shift(1) + temp.shift(1), df['Pickup Time'])
```

Now your `df` looks as follows:

```
   Route  Sequence          First Stop Drive Time         Pickup Time
0    123         1 2019-11-02 17:22:41   00:26:38 2019-11-02 16:56:03
1    123         2 2019-11-02 17:22:41   00:07:30 2019-11-02 17:22:41
2    123         3 2019-11-02 17:22:41   00:02:44 2019-11-02 17:30:11
3    123         4 2019-11-02 17:22:41   00:16:25 2019-11-02 17:32:55
4    123         5 2019-11-02 17:22:41   00:18:04 2019-11-02 17:49:20
5    125         1 2019-11-02 19:22:41   00:16:38 2019-11-02 19:06:03
6    125         2 2019-11-02 19:22:41   00:08:30 2019-11-02 19:22:41
7    125         3 2019-11-02 19:22:41   00:04:44 2019-11-02 19:31:11
8    125         4 2019-11-02 19:22:41   00:16:25 2019-11-02 19:35:55
9    125         5 2019-11-02 19:22:41   00:12:04 2019-11-02 19:52:20
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it does the job.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not quite what I'm looking for yet.

What you show in index 2 is the 'Pickup Time' of Sequence 1 (index 0) plus the the 'Drive Time' of index 2. What I actually want for index 2 is the 'Pickup Time' of index 1 plus the 'Drive Time' of index 1. And for index 3 is the 'Pickup Time' of index 2 plus the 'Drive Time of index 2. 

In Pandas, I can't get it to reference the previous row since I'm defining that previous row in my calculation.